# Measuring precise distances over a table top range

Tags: experimental-physics, interferometry

I need to measure distances on a table top (3-5 feet) to a precision of 0.0001" inches or even better yet to the micron, which is 40% smaller. This is about 0.15 arcseconds.

My understanding is that laser pulse ranging does not work at this scale and that the normal approach is to use [interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometry).

The problem is that there are about 20 different major types of interferometric methods and I am not sure which one (or ones) are most relevant to this kind of problem and scale. What type of interferometry is most applicable to measurement at this scale?

Comment: Interferometers measure small differences in path length, rather than large distances.  It seems unlikely to me that you really need to measure a distance of 3-5 ft to the nearest micron.  This may be a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in  which you ask about your *proposed solution* rather than the *actual problem* which you are trying to solve. If you describe your *actual problem* the community may be able to help you better.

Comment: You might consider computing the expected relative shift due to thermal expansion on the range of temperatures in a typical dwelling. Unless you have a temperature stabilized environment your least significant figures are going to be unreliable on time-scales of hours no matter how perfect the measurement.

Comment: @dmckee I am aware of the temperature requirements for doing the measurements accurately.

Comment: Well, this goes back to sammy's comment - what exactly are you trying to do? One can (actively) hold things stable wrt each other without needing a measurement with 5-6 significant figures.

Comment: @JonCuster I didn't say I need 6 significant figures, I just said I needed it to be within 0.0001". I only need 2 significant figures. In other words if the instrument has a read range of 0.0000" to 0.0099" with an error of +/- 0.00005 that is good enough.

Comment: OK, I am confused. Your question states you want to measure distances on a table top (3-5 feet, call it a meter) to a precision of a micron. That would be a measurement to one part in $10^{6}$ (meter -> micron). 2 significant figures on a meter would be measuring to a cm, doable with a tape measure. So, what are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: @JonCuster I think you may have a misunderstanding of what significant figures are. You may want to re-read a physics textbook on that subject or see the Wikipedia. Significant figures are invariant to scale. For example, the number 0.00052 has two significant figures.

Comment: I think I have a very good idea of what significant figure are, and trying to measure to within one micron across 1 meter is not 2 significant figures. Try again.

Comment: @JonCuster I am not trying to measure a micron over a meter. I am trying to discriminate a micron at a distance of about a meter. What I am looking for here is somebody with a good knowledge of interferometer types so they can point me in the direction of the right kind of technology, not a critique of my experimental design.

Comment: Do you mean that you are tying to measure a very small angle?

Answer (score 1):

I did further research on this problem and discovered that the relevant technology is called *displacement measurement interferometry* or DMI. There are two basic types of instruments: a homodyne and heterodyne interferometer. The homodyne is the simpler of the two types.

There is a document widely available on the web which covers all the basics entitled "[Primer on Displacement Measuring Interferometers](http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/laser/dmiprim.pdf)".